# AngularJS ng-repeat messing up with order

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created an Javascript object the following way:

```
$scope.initNews = function () {
    for (var i = 2013; i > 2000; i--) {
        $scope.news[i] = {};
        $scope.news[i]["year"] = Number(i);
        for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
            $scope.news[i][j] = {};
            $scope.news[i][j]["month"] = $scope.month_names[j-1];
        }
    }
};
```

but ng-repeat seems to mess up with the way it loops through the items.

```
<ul ng-repeat="old_news_year in news">{{old_news_year.year}}
    <li ng-repeat="old_news_month in old_news_year">{{$index + 1}}. {{old_news_month.month}}</li>
</ul>
```

For the whole sample, check http://jsfiddle.net/tFewZ/1/

> **EDIT**
>  I am under the impression (by adding a "debugger;" into the code)
>   that AngularJS is looping through the entries according to their
>   $$hashKey and not according to their Javascript index...

> *Still do not understand about the 13th element though... is this the prototype attribute?*

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Guillaume

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, for the benefit of others. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use $index instead of the collection approach ('in').

```
<ul ng-repeat="old_news_year in news">{{old_news_year.year}}
    <li ng-repeat="old_news_month in old_news_year">
      {{$index + 1}}. {{old_news_year[$index+1].month}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

> Check: http://jsfiddle.net/guillaume1978/XmSTK/2/